# Tons of white space below jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I have searched on here for this answer and haven't found a specific answer for this.
Here is the url
http://billcorbitt.com/TimYoung/index.html

I finally go the images to show properly, but I cannot get rid of the excess white space below the images.  I would greatly appreciate help here.  Please note I'm a novice at this so please explain like I'm a five-year-old.  LOL.

I've tried numerous settings and cannot get anything to work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: Changing margins to Auto: 0, also removing the JS slider and still had enormous amounts of white space?  changed images to "block" to read simpler....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify the same size for both 'outer container' and 'slides' container.

```
<div id="jssor_1" style="position:relative;margin:0 auto;top:0px;left:0px;width:1300px;height:1100px;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;">

<div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;width:1500px;height:800px;overflow:hidden;">
```

Change size of both elements above to either 1300x100 or 1500x800.